# Enviar o que está sendo digitado de um input para outro em tempo real

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, galera!
Não entendo de JQuery ou javascript, somente PHP.
Estou sofrendo para criar um INPUT 1, que em tempo real, envia o que está sendo digitado para um INPUT 2, sem espaços ou caracteres especiais.
Atualmente trato isso em PHP.
Exemplo:

```
<form>
  <label>Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="INPUT1">

  <!-- Recebe os dados do INPUT 1 sem espaços e caracteres especiais-->
  <label>Url</label>
  https://meusite.com.br/<input type="text" name="INPUT2">
</form>
```

Espero que tenha sido claro e aguardo ajuda da comunidade.

Comment: _"sem espaços ou caracteres especiais"_ - o input1 recebe coisas que queres filtrar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Falando de uma forma simples para entender, você pode fazer assim.

```js
function trim(str) {
   return str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '' )
}

let input = document.getElementById('um')
let input2 = document.getElementById('dois')

input.onkeyup = function(){ 
  input2.value = trim(input.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="um" placeholder="Input 1">

<input tyoe="text" id="dois" placeholder="Input 2">
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas no segundo input não pode ir (permitir) caracteres especiais ou espaços.

Comment: @MárcioTeixeira Editei a resposta, espero que ajude

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar regex para trocar caracteres especiais ou espaços por nada.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('um')
let input2 = document.getElementById('dois')

input.onkeyup = function(){
  let valor = input.value.replace(/[^\w\s]|\s/gi, '');
  input2.value = valor
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="um" placeholder="Input 1">

<input type="text" id="dois" placeholder="Input 2">
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, utilizando regex para filtrar os caracteres especiais

```js
$('#input1').on('change keyup', function () {
  $('#input2').val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text"/>
<input id="input2" type="text"/>
```